# How to send 2 parameters in body with retrofit?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Good night everybody.
I need to do a POST request and I'm using Retrofit 2 to do this.
But the Api I'm consuming does not give me these parameters in the API response, just in the body.

**Api Response**

[image: API response Image]

I already searched in some places but I did not find anything that could help me.

**My interface Class**

```
public interface LoginApi {
    @POST("api/login")
    Call<UserAccount> doLogin(@Body Login login);
}
```

**My Model Class**

```
public class Login {
    public String user;
    public String password;
}
```

**My API response class**

```
public class UserAccount {
    @SerializedName("userId")
    @Expose
    private Integer userId;

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("bankAccount")
    @Expose
    private String bankAccount;

    @SerializedName("agency")
    @Expose
    private String agency;

    @SerializedName("balance")
    @Expose
    private Double balance;
}
```

**My call class**

```
public class LoginPresenter {

    private LoginView loginView;
    private ServiceConfig serviceConfig;

    public LoginPresenter() {
        this.loginView = loginView;

        if (this.serviceConfig == null) {
            this.serviceConfig = new ServiceConfig();
        }
    }

    public void doLogin(Login login) {
        serviceConfig
                .login()
                .doLogin(login)
                .enqueue(new Callback<UserAccount>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<UserAccount> call, Response<UserAccount> response) {
                        UserAccount userAccount = response.body();
                        assert userAccount != null;
                        Log.e("Agency:",userAccount.getAgency());
                        Log.e("BankAccount:", userAccount.getBankAccount());
                        Log.e("Name:", userAccount.getName());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<UserAccount> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.d("Erro", t.getMessage());
                    }
                });
        }
}
```

**My Activity**

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements LoginView {

    private EditText edtUser, edtPassword;
    private Button btnLogin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        edtUser = findViewById(R.id.edt_user);
        edtPassword = findViewById(R.id.edt_password);
        btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        final LoginPresenter loginPresenter = new LoginPresenter();
        final Login login = new Login();
        login.user = edtUser.getText().toString();
        login.password = edtPassword.getText().toString();
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                loginPresenter.doLogin(login);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void userAccount(List<UserAccount> userAccount) {

    }
}
```

I hope I have made my problem clear and that someone who has been through it can help me.
Appreciate.

Comment: It's unclear what do you want to _post_ and what are you expecting to _receive_.

Comment: I need to make a request via POST by passing two parameters in the body as I showed in the image, to get the response data from the API.

Comment: `Login` class already contains both parameters you need. It's serialization via any `JSON` serializer will produce an object like on that picture from postman. This part of your code is correct. I guess you missed `GsonConverterFactory` in `Retrofit` configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `@Body JsonObject body` instead of `@Body Login login`

Here is full code:

Your interface will be:

```
public interface LoginApi {
    @POST("api/login")
    Call<UserAccount> doLogin(@Body JsonObject body);
}
```

How to Create JsonObject :

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
jsonObject.addProperty("user", userValue);
jsonObject.addProperty("password", passwordValue);
```

Pass it from your activity to presenter.

Hope it will works for you.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Pass Like This:-

**You Interface**

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    String URL_BASE = "Base Url";

    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("login")
    Call<User> getUser(@Body String body);

}
```

**Activity**

```
public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Callback<User> {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ApiInterface.URL_BASE)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        ApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);


        // prepare call in Retrofit 2.0
        try {
            JSONObject paramObject = new JSONObject();
            paramObject.put("email", "sample@gmail.com");
            paramObject.put("pass", "4384984938943");

            Call<User> userCall = apiInterface.getUser(paramObject.toString());
            userCall.enqueue(this);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
    }
}
```